# impossible aligned inline-block menu

Tags: html, css

So I have this horizontal menu with lines under it, but my text keeps getting all weird: 
[image]

I tried to fix with display:inline, but it turns my line into slices under each word. [image]

What I want: aligned menu (like the 2nd pic) with a straight line (pic 1).

```css
/* Navigation */
#undefined-sticky-wrapper {position:relative;height:0 !important;}
.menu {
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 width:100%;
 height:76px;
 background:#000000;
 z-index:9999;
}
#logo {
 float:left;
 margin-bottom:0;
 margin-left:0;
}

#nav {
 text-align: center;
}
.navigation{
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
}
ul.navigation {
 overflow-x:hidden;
 position:relative;
 text-align:center;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:0;
 width:770px;
}
.navigation li{
 display:inline-block;
 text-align:center;
 width:128px;
 padding:28px 0 12px;
 margin:0 -2.5px;
 text-transform:none;
 background:none;
 border-bottom:1px solid #393939;
 font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
 font-weight:300;
 font-size:15px;
 line-height:20px;
 color:#a3a3a3;
 transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.navigation li:hover,
.navigation .active {
 cursor:pointer;
 color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="undefined-sticky-wrapper" class="sticky-wrapper is-sticky" style="height: 76px;"><div class="menu" style="position: fixed; height: 56px; margin-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 20px; top: 0px;"> 
 <div class="container clearfix">
  
  <div id="nav">
   <a class="btn_dropdown" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse_">MENU</a>
   <ul class="navigation ph-line-nav">
    <li data-slide="2" class="">FORMAÇÃO</li>
    <li data-slide="4" class="">SKILLS</li>
    <li data-slide="6" class="">EXPERIÊNCIA</li>
    <li data-slide="8" class="">PREMIAÇÕES</li>
    <li data-slide="10" class="">PORTIFÓLIO</li>
    <li data-slide="12" class="">CONTATO</li>
    <div class="effect"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
   </ul>
  </div>
 
 </div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: now check ur code is it working fine u can margin between menus

Answer (score 0):

([Answered by the OP in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que))

> With the help of shanidkv w/margins it helped my menu alignment!
>
> About the under line, in case I found out it is a border, so I just used `border-collapse:collapse`
>
> and now I feel so stupid